# How to resize material-ui's tabs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get a result looking like this (picture taken from https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage):

[image: What I want]

I don't want the tabs to take 100% of the width of the page, as it is by default with material-ui. Is it possible to do this with the implementation of material-ui ? I already played with the width of each tab using the `style` tab property, but the inkbare seems hardcoded to use percentages according to the id of the selected tab, and therefore doesn't underline properly the resized tabs. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an issue related to this problem https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1203

But yes, there is an easy workaround. (unfortunately it doesnt support diffrent widths across the tabs).
You can use the Tabs `tabItemContainerStyle` property to set the width of the tabs container (make it the width you want to each tab times the number of tabs).
Since the background color is setted on that element, you're gonna need to override the styles for two others Tabs properties (`style` and `contentContainerStyle`).

In this example Im setting the same color as my tabs in the `style` property (for the whole component) and setting the `contentContainerStyle` back to a white background.
You could use the classes properties as well..

Ex: (Imagine you have a blue toolbar)

```
<Tabs 
  tabItemContainerStyle={{width: '400px'}}
  style={{background: 'blue'}}
  contentContainerStyle={{background: '#FFF'}} >
```

Comment: It worked, the tabs are resized and the inkbar follows. One small disappointment is that I wanted to add a shadow on the tabs, now that the tabs are not taking all the screen the shadow doesn't cover all the width of the screen. Also, what if I want to center the tabs? I can do it adding `margin:auto` but then the inkbar is lost. Modifying the css in the browser I could locate a div on which to apply `margin:auto` on the inkbar, but it is not available from outside the material-ui component.

Comment: Well, in that case you could use the `className` property.  
ex: `className div:nth-child(2)` - this way you could set that element the margin: auto..

Comment: It's working, but since the tabs item is containing the pages in each tab, this forces all the second child divs below in the hierarchy to have `margin:auto`. Here is a small jsfiddle to present my point: http://jsfiddle.net/mattderferf/va1bsqv2/

Comment: what about `className > div:nth-child(2)` ? http://jsfiddle.net/va1bsqv2/3/

Comment: It's perfect ! Thanks

Comment: For those who wonder how to solve the shadow issue, I created a shadow div just under the inkbar (for all my different tabs) with the following attributes: 
`shadowTrick:{
    width:"100%", 
    height: '5px',
    boxShadow: '0px 3px 5px #888888',
    marginTop: '-5px',
    backgroundColor: '#your background color here'
  }`
Then I changed the zIndex of the inkbar to display it above the shadow.

Comment: is it possible to use the `div:nth-child` trick when passing the style directly inline to the react component with `style=` ? I want `width=auto` for the tabs (tabs names have different lengths and the inkbar to resize accordingly.

Comment: Material-ui: once again, making simple things complex! ugh :(